# Unable to start sparkling shell in Windows

Tags: apache-spark, sparkling-water

I am running `Windows 10` and using `Scala 2.11` and `spark version 2.2.1`. Spark_home is also configured and path is also added to it's bin and I can start spark-shell directly from command prompt from any directory.

But then when I run `sparkling-shell.cmd`, I get a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" message.

Am I missing a critical step in the setup?

**EDIT**: Below is the console output after turning `echo` `on`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>sparkling-shell.cmd

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem This is the entry point for running Spark shell. To avoid polluting the

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem environment, it just launches a new cmd to do the real work.

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>cmd /V /E /C C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\sparkling-shell2.cmd

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem Top-level directory for this product

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set TOPDIR=C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\bin\sparkling-env.cmd

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if not defined TOPDIR (
echo Caller has to setup TOPDIR variable!
 exit /b -1
)

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem Version of this distribution

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('TYPE C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\gradle.properties | findstr /r "^version="') do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('TYPE C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\gradle.properties | findstr /r "^h2oMajorVersion="') do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('TYPE C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\gradle.properties | findstr /r "^h2oBuild="') do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('TYPE C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\gradle.properties | findstr /r "^h2oMajorName="') do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('TYPE C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\gradle.properties | findstr /r "^sparkVersion="') do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %i in ('TYPE C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\gradle.properties | findstr /r "^scalaBaseVersion="') do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem Ensure that scala version contains only major version

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %j in ("2.11") do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %i in ("2.2.1") do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=1 delims=-" %i in ("2.2.10") do ()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>()

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem Fat jar for this distribution

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set FAT_JAR=sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.2.10-all.jar

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set FAT_JAR_FILE=C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\assembly\build\libs\sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.2.10-all.jar

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set PY_ZIP=h2o_pysparkling_2.2-2.2.10.zip

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set PY_ZIP_FILE=C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\py\build\dist\h2o_pysparkling_2.2-2.2.10.zip

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem Setup loging and output

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set tmpdir=C:\Users\abcUser\AppData\Local\Temp

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set SPARK_LOG_DIR=C:\Users\abcUser\AppData\Local\Temp\spark\logs

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set SPARK_WORKER_DIR=C:\Users\abcUser\AppData\Local\Temp\spark\work

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=C:\Users\abcUser\AppData\Local\Temp\spark\work

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set DEFAULT_MASTER=local[*]

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set DEFAULT_DRIVER_MEMORY=2G

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set LIBSW=C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\bin\libsw.cmd

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem Verify there is Spark installation

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\bin\libsw.cmd checkSparkHome

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call:checkSparkHome

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>rem Example class prefix

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if not exist "C:\spark/bin/spark-submit.cmd" (
echo Please setup SPARK_HOME variable to your Spark installation!
 call :haltHelper  2>nul
)

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>exit /b 0

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>exit /b

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\bin\libsw.cmd checkSparkVersion

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call:checkSparkVersion

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call :checkJava

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set "JV="

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "tokens=3" %A in ('java -version 2>&1') do if not defined JV set "JV=%~A"

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if not defined JV set "JV=1.8.0_161"

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if not defined JV set "JV=Runtime"

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if not defined JV set "JV=64-Bit"

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if /I "1.8.0_161" == "not" (
echo Java is not installed. Please install Java first before continuing with Sparkling Water.
 call :haltHelper  2>nul
)

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>exit /b 0

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>for /F "delims=" %i in ('CMD /C C:\spark/bin/spark-submit.cmd --version 2>&1 1>NUL | findstr /v "Scala" | findstr "version" ') do set linewithversion=%i

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set linewithversion=   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.1

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>set INSTALLED_SPARK_VERSION=2.2.1

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if NOT "2.2.1" == "2.2.1" (
echo You are trying to use Sparkling Water built for Spark 2.2.1, but your %SPARK_HOME(=C:\spark) property points to Spark of version 2.2.1. Please ensure correct Spark is provided and re-run Sparkling Water.
 call :haltHelper  2>nul
)

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>exit /b 0

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>exit /b

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\bin\libsw.cmd checkFatJarExists

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>call:checkFatJarExists
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>if not exist "C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin\..\assembly\build\libs\sparkling-water-assembly_2.11-2.2.10-all.jar (

C:\DriveD\Other\sparkling-water-2.2.10\bin>
```

Comment: What's the value of `SPARK_HOME`? I guess it has a space that confuses `sparkling-shell.cmd`. Edit the cmd file and set `echo` on.

Comment: It is C:\spark for SPARK_HOME.

Comment: After making echo on, it is showing "Caller has to setup TOPDIR variable!"

Comment: That's the issue, isn't it? --> _"call:checkFatJarExists
The syntax of the command is incorrect."_?

Comment: What is that FatJar it is looking for?

Comment: I've got no idea, but what I think the error says (screams?) to add a space between `call` and `:checkFatJarExists`.